# MySQL Left Join Not Working As I Expected

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

Table Name : Feature

```
+--------+----------+
| fea_id | fea_name |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | Price    |
|      2 | Height   |
|      3 | Weight   |
+--------+----------+
```

Table Name : property_meta

```
+----+--------+--------+-------+
| id   | fea_id | pro_id | value |
+----+--------+--------+-------+
|  100 |      1 |    300 |  2500 |
|  200 |      2 |    300 |   300 |
|  
+----+--------+--------+-------+
```

My Query

`SELECT * FROM feature LEFT JOIN property_meta ON feature.fea_id = property_meta.fea_id where property_meta.pro_id=300 GROUP by feature.fea_id ORDER BY feature.fea_id ASC`

Expected Result

```
+--------+--------+-------+
| fea_id | pro_id | value |
+--------+--------+-------+
|      1 |    300 | 2500  |
|      2 |    300 | 300   |
|      3 |    300 | NULL  |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

But I am getting **without the last row**. **I need that last row also**. How I modify my query to get the last row also?

That means I need to get all rows of Feature table even there is no value in property meta table.

Comment: Why would pro_id be 300 for fea_id = 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`where property_meta.pro_id=300` makes your `left join` to an `inner join`.
Add this to the on clause and it is working:

```
SELECT * FROM feature LEFT JOIN property_meta ON feature.fea_id = property_meta.fea_id and property_meta.pro_id=300 GROUP by feature.fea_id ORDER BY feature.fea_id ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM feature LEFT JOIN property_meta ON feature.fea_id = property_meta.fea_id and property_meta.pro_id=300 GROUP by feature.fea_id ORDER BY feature.fea_id ASC
```

Put the where condition into the join condition as the where condition restricts the result and the join condition only the joined tables

Comment: Do not enter code only. Explain what you have done and why

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM feature LEFT JOIN property_meta 

ON feature.fea_id = property_meta.fea_id 
   AND property_meta.pro_id=300 -- <-- need to move this condition here or the where clause will remove the last row

GROUP by feature.fea_id ORDER BY feature.fea_id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

`where property_meta.pro_id=300` removes that line, cause this will be `null` after the unsuccessfull join.

remove that condition and you will have

```
+--------+--------+-------+
| fea_id | pro_id | value |
+--------+--------+-------+
|      1 |    300 | 2500  |
|      2 |    300 | 300   |
|      3 |    NULL| NULL  |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

Fix accordingly :)

Comment: I can't remove pro_id=300 because there are lots of pro_id's in property_meta. I need to get only for product id 300. Ex: Price of product id 300.

Comment: @DamithRuwan Its just an example why the line is removed. Add the condition to the `join` rather than `where` as outlined by Jens.

Comment: Yes, Thanks. I solved my question using Jens Answer. Thanks for you too. I am not the person who down vote your answer.

Comment: No problem :-) idk about downvotes of people expecting a copy&paste solution. (From your current query i expected you to be able to fix it, once you "see" why the row vanishes)